# Is $G$ going to be cyclic of order $n$ and also isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I heard that if we have a group with $n$ elements and there is an element $x \in G$ with $|x| = n$ then $G$ is going to be cyclic of order $n$ and also isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n$. How is it true that it must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n$? Is this result related to the result of $G$ being an abelian group with $|G| = p^2$ where $p$ is a prime then $G \simeq \mathbb{Z/p} \times \mathbb{Z/p}$ or $\mathbb{Z/p^2}$? Lastly, is there an easy way to tell if a group is cyclic and if so how would you tell the above is cyclic?

Comment: Every element in $G$ can be written as $x^i$, so consider $\phi(x^i) = i$

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish How does that mean it is isomorphic? I think if all elements are of order $n$ and the group is cyclic it is true. Why is it true if there is just one?

Comment: It doesn't, but show $\phi$ is a homomorphism (not too hard) and that it is a bijection (by finding an inverse or making a counting argument).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the direct isomorphism from $G = \langle x \rangle$ to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$,
$$\phi(x^m) = m.$$
Clearly this is a surjective homomorphism. As these two groups have the same number of elements, it is also injective, and thus an isomorphism.

More generally, there is only one cyclic group of order $n$ up to isomorphism, with similarly given isomorphism.

Your second claim, that if $|G| = p^2$ then $G \simeq \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is incorrect. For instance, $G$ might be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ (and these are the only two groups of prime squared order, up to isomorphism).

Comment: Can you prove your claim that "More generally, there is only one cyclic group of order $n$ up to isomorphism, with similarly given isomorphism."?

Comment: @Puzzled417 It's actually exactly that isomorphism. You can show that the cyclic group of order $n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ using the $\phi$ map. Then compose these two isomorphisms to get the isomorphism you want.

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is a cyclic group of order n, let $x\in G$ be an element such that $G=\langle x\rangle$. For all $a\in G$ there is a unic $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x^{m}=a$. This define a surjective homomorphism of rings $$\begin{array}{cccc}\varphi:&\mathbb{Z}&\rightarrow&G\\&m&\mapsto&x^{m}\end{array}$$
where $ker(\varphi)=\{m\mathbb{Z}:n|m\}=n\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\simeq G.$$

If $|G|=p^{2}$ then $G\simeq\mathbb{Z}_{p^{2}}$. You can see that $\mathbb{Z}_{p}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ does not a cyclic group.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the $\phi:G\to \mathbb{Z}/n$ with $\phi(x)=1.$  One can verify that this is an isomorphism. A useful property is that for a homomorphism between groups $\phi(x^n)=\phi(x)^n.$ This is related to the other group that you mentioned in the sense that all finite abelian groups can be classified. This classification is often the goal of introductory abstract algebra courses. Lastly, in order to show a group is cyclic you must find a generator or show your group is isomorphic to a cyclic group.